# Use Conditional Formatting to Highlight Cells Red or Green if Higher than Previous Cell

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, google-docs, conditional-formatting

I need help formatting cells to be highlighted red(if lower) or green(if higher) than the cell above.

For example: 
450 (neutral-since its the first cell, not sure what color it would be)
500 (Green)
300(Red)
800(Green)
700(Red)

Thank you

Still having trouble with that formula, it shows "invalid" :([my example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfhG4.png)

I kind of need something like this example (EXCEPT i don't need the yellow if its the same value, it can stay green) [example of what I need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM3Yz.png)

Comment: Your picture show google sheets not Excel.  Please fix your tags, they are not the same.

Comment: Also you are missing a second `"` on the `B5<>""` part.

Comment: Did you try the fix I suggested?  The formula should work if you put two `""` instead of what you have.

Comment: Your new screenshot, just make your `=A1=A2` formatting green background? Or just remove it and make the other formula `=A1<=A2`.  Edit: wait - you want the yellow `6` to be green? Then just change the format as I mentioned first. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

For Green, you can use:

```
=AND(A2<>"",A2>A1)
```

and for Red:

```
=AND(A2<>"",A2<A1)
```

Both applied to range `=$A$2:$A$100`

[image]

(Note: You can just do `=A2>A1` and skip the `AND()` if you adjust the "Applied To" range to fit your data exactly. I just did `A2:A100`, so added the `=AND(A2<>"",...)` to prevent blank cells from being highlighted.)

Comment: I have a data list of numbers Week over week and I want the cell to highlight green if it was higher than the previous week or Red if it was lower

Comment: @ChristopherManguerra - Okay. Does the above not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help Bruce. Unfortunately it is not working when I apply this formula (I am using Google Sheets for this). 450 and 300 become green, but 800 does not (I can't seem to find out why)

Comment: @ChristopherManguerra - What's the exact formula, and exact "Applies To" range?  Can you post a screenshot (or link to one in a comment) of what you have?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16iSgXc4_qcHTiiKGSh75qtO3o8fPcsqpkECOAnKY_es/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Bruce, the data is just a small sample set. I have to rack data Week over week and I want the data to turn Green if it is higher than the previous week or red if it is lower.

Comment: @ChristopherManguerra - can you post a screenshot? I'm always leery of opening documents from online.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, totally understand. I will post it in the original post.

Comment: @ChristopherManguerra - Thanks!  Change the `Apply To` range to `A2:A1000` see if that does it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bruce, unfortunately I still can't get it to work (its a little frustrating). I'm sure it's something simple to do but luck ism't on my side today. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Bruce, update. I finally got it to work. It turns out I was using A1 instead of A2. Now I used this for my long list and it worked out. Thank you soo much for your help. @BruceWayne